# Why is the Kronecker symbol $(n/2)$ conventionally defined as it is?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history

Admittedly this may be an extremely naive question, but I am simply puzzled about the motivation behind choosing this function to be one of the Dirichlet characters modulo $8$, rather than the Dirichlet character modulo $2$ (or, indeed, any other character modulo $8$). There must be a good reason for this, right? What was Kronecker's motivation?

For $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\notin 2\mathbb{N}$, the Kronecker symbol $(m/n)$ is the completely multiplicative extension to the odd numbers of the Legendre symbol $(m/p)$, where $p$ is an odd prime. That is,

$$\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)=\prod_{p|n}\left(\frac{m}{p}\right)^{\alpha_p(n)},$$
where $\alpha_p(n)$ is the exponent of $p$ in the factorisation of $n$ and $\left(\frac{m}{p}\right)$ is $0$ if $p|m$ and $\{-1,1\}$ depending on whether $m$ is a quadratic non-reside or residue (mod $p$), respectively.

Very well. When $n\in 2\mathbb{N}$, however, Kronecker's symbol is defined in the same way but with $(m/2)$ defined to be $0$ if $m$ is even, $1$ if $m\equiv \pm 1$ (mod 8) and $-1$ $m\equiv \pm 3$ (mod 8). In other words, Kronecker's symbol the Dirichlet character modulo $8$ that takes the values $1,0,-1,0,-1,0,1,0,...$.

> Of course, there are four characters (mod $8$) which are all real, completely multiplicative functions of $m$. For example, the simplest of these is the Dirichlet character (mod $2$), which takes the values $1,0,...$. In particular, had we taken Kronecker's symbol to be this character, then it would still be completely multiplicative as a function of $n$ and when $n=2$ we would have a function of $m$ that carries the trivial structure of residuosity (mod $2$), too. So why do we take it to be the particular character we do, instead?

Comment: The motivation is quadratic reciprocity, the Artin map of $O_K,K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, the embedding in $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{Disc(O_K)})$, and the factorization of the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_K(s)=\zeta(s)L(s,\chi)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol#Connection_to_Dirichlet_characters

Comment: @reuns Please would you elaborate on this explanation with some details? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know quadratic reciprocity ? Do you know how it relates to the Artin map of $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ where $d$ is squarefree ? The Kronecker symbol $(\frac{d}{.})$ is the Artin map, the completely multiplicative extension of $(\frac{d}{p})= 1,-1,0$ if $(p)$ splits, is inert or ramified in $O_K$. The quadratic reciprocity follows from the embedding $K\to \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_\Delta)$ and the fact that the Artin map of the latter depends only on congruences $\bmod \Delta$.

Comment: Okay that makes some sense - so you're saying that the algebraic structure of the number fields determines the values of the characters and, specifically, this works for $p=2$ also?

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" definition of the Kronecker symbol is the following. Let $D$ be the discriminant of a quadratic number field and $p$ a nonramified prime. Then $(D/p) = +1$ or $-1$ according as $p$ splits or is inert. Thus the Kronecker symbol encodes the splitting of primes in quadratic extensions (which is what the Artin symbol does in arbitrary abelian extensions). The extension to composite values of $p$ is
achieved by multiplicativity.

If $K = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2})$, then $D = 8$, and $(D/p) = +1$
if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$, and $(D/p) = -1$ if $p \equiv 5 \bmod 8$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is quadratic residues and Legendre's
symbol $\,\big(\frac{a}{p}\big).\,$ In particular the
Legendre symbol $\,\big(\frac2{p}\big).\,$ It can be
proved that $2$ is a quadratic residue of primes
of the form $\,8n+1\,$ or $\,8n+7\,$ and a quadratic
nonresidue of primes of the form $\,8n+3\,$ or
$\,8n+5.\,$ This can be expressed by the formula
$\,\big(\frac2{p}\big) = (-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}\,$
which is contained in the Wikipedia article on
[Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Somos. But how does this fact imply that we should define $(p/2)$ as we do?

Comment: As stated in the Wikipedia article "the Legendre symbol is a multiplicative function with values 1, −1, 0 that is a quadratic character modulo an odd prime number p: its value at a (nonzero) quadratic residue mod p is 1 and at a non-quadratic residue (non-residue) is −1. Its value at zero is 0. "